# displaying info from db with rails doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm actually working on a simple rails app. I generated a **Rails g scaffold Course**.

[Picture of folders generated by the scaffold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0oLC.png)

Now i want to display all the courses that i create, with a title, a picture and a short description. **here is the code to do it**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Courses</h1>
<div class="row">
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', course %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_path(course) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', course, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          <%= image_tag( course.image, width: 250, height: 250) %>
          <div class="caption">
            <h3><% course.title %></h3>
            <p><% course.description %></p>
            <%= link_to 'that course', course_path(course), class:"btn btn-default"%>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
<%= link_to 'New Course', new_course_path %>
```

**With this, the picture is displayed, but not the title and the description neither** 
Html is made by rails to make the title and the description, but it stay empty. [Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyRKz.png)

I suppose that i made a mistake somewhere but i can't figure it out.

ps: **I checked with the rails console, the title and the description exist in my database**

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
<h3><% course.title %></h3>
<p><% course.description %></p>
```

Should be

```
<h3><%= course.title %></h3>
<p><%= course.description %></p>
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir :) Hey, that happened to everybody ;)

Comment: Thx ! Merry Christmas by the way :)

Comment: Merry Christmas :)